# Archiving SQL Server data table data?

Tags: sql-server

We have a table with millions of records. We need to archive records older than 3 whats best way of archiving old data of SQL Server database tables?

Comment: "Archive" is a vague and ambiguous term.  Please clarify what characteristics your archived data would have different from you non-archived data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess it depends on the structure of your database, and what you need to do with this archive records. Do they need to be accessible from your application? Do you just need them somewhere so that you can query against it in the future using ad-hoc queries?

Options may include: creating an "Archive Database" where you move the older table records and everything linked to it (foreign key tables), creating an ArchiveTable, or something more complex like [Creating Partitioned Tables](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188730%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) (`Sql Server 2005 +`)

More Info:

1. [Partitioning & Archiving tables in SQL Server (Part 1: The basics)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/felixmar/archive/2011/02/14/partitioning-amp-archiving-tables-in-sql-server-part-1-the-basics.aspx)
2. [Partitioning & Archiving tables in SQL Server (Part 2: Split, Merge and Switch partitions)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/felixmar/archive/2011/08/29/partitioning-amp-archiving-tables-in-sql-server-part-2-split-merge-and-switch-partitions.aspx)